# SQLAlchemy - How to Return list of Users from database where is_active is True?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

The following example works and returns a list of users based on the limit arguments.

```
def get_users(skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100):
    with Session(engine) as session:
        return session.query(User).offset(skip).limit(limit).all()
```

I want to get a similar list but only where `is_active=True` in the users database table. The column is_active exists and the fields contain True.

The query I have returns

```
[Previous line repeated 991 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Stack Trace

```
File "/Users/davethomson/git/github.com/serup.ai/serupai-backend/auth/./routers/admin.py", line 29, in get_active_users
    active_users = get_active_users()
  File "/Users/davethomson/git/github.com/serup.ai/serupai-backend/auth/./routers/admin.py", line 29, in get_active_users
    active_users = get_active_users()
  File "/Users/davethomson/git/github.com/serup.ai/serupai-backend/auth/./routers/admin.py", line 29, in get_active_users
    active_users = get_active_users()
  [Previous line repeated 991 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I have tried doing but returns recursion error.

Response schema (schemas.py)

```
class UserBase(BaseModel):
    id: int

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True



class UserAll(UserBase):
    email: str
    username: str
```

User Class

```py
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    updated_at = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow, onupdate=datetime.utcnow)
    username = Column(String)
    email = Column(String)
    password = Column(String)
    is_active = Column(Boolean, default=True)

    roles = relationship("UserToRole", cascade="all, delete", back_populates="user")
```

FastAPI calling get_active_users

```
@router.get("/users/active", response_model=List[UserAll])
def get_active_users(limit: int = 100, current_user=Depends(user_role)):
    active_users = get_active_users()
    return active_users
```

get_active_users.py

```py
def get_active_users(limit: int = 100):
    with Session(engine) as session:
        users = session.query(User).filter(User.is_active == True).all()
return users
```

Also tried this variant

```py
def get_active_users(limit: int = 100):
    with Session(engine) as session:
        users = session.query(User).filter(User.is_active == True).all()
        active_users = []
        for user in users:
            active_users.append(user)
            return active_users
```

And the select statement works fine.

```sql
SELECT * FROM users WHERE is_active=True;
```

Comment: Can you also add the definition of the `User` class and the exact place that causes `RecursionError`?

Comment: Just figured out my issue, had a Fastapi route runction with the same name as the function I am importing.

Answer (score 0):

Change the variable name from is_active to something else, it will works perfectly fine. Apparently is_active has conflict with some builtin function.

https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

In the above link under "Anonymous Users" section you can see the built in function by default for is_active is to false, so it's more like a keyword you cannot use is_active as a variable. The conflict with method and variable name being same.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).